# Scala - programming a deck of cards

Tags: scala

so i have a task to make a deck of cards using scala. Im good at object oriented programming and so i made this in a few minutes. Now its time for me to learn functional programming. Oh boy.. Where do i begin with this? How do i even construct these cards? I was thinking maybe i shouls have 3 parallel arrays of information? For specific card id, face and suit? I can use enumerators for values but how do i actually initialize these arrays? Currently im stuck at using arrays. Maybe i should make a list? If so, how would i initialize them as well?
-Thank you!!

Comment: Please post some code (even your java code) and describe the kinds of operations you would like to support.

Comment: I'm not clear on why changing from some object you created to using a List in Scala is more functional than what you had before. But I think that's a very open discussion. Better to have some concrete code and question on how to do it in Scala.

Comment: Functional programming is about algorithms not data structures, so you can use the same data structure you would use for object-oriented programming. You need to tell us what you are doing with the cards and then we can explain how to do it in a functional way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible implementation in scala:

```
// algebraic data types are usually used in scala for enum-like concepts
sealed trait Suit
object Suit {
  case object Diamond extends Suit
  case object Spade extends Suit
  case object Club extends Suit
  case object Heart extends Suit
  val all = List(Diamond, Spade, Club, Heart)
}
sealed trait Card
case class NumberCard (number: Int, suit: Suit) extends Card {
  require(number >= 1 && number <= 13, s"Invalid card number: $number") 
}
case object Joker extends Card

val deck: List[Card] = Joker :: Joker :: (for {
  suit <- Suit.all
  number <- 1 to 13
} yield NumberCard(number, suit))
```

How you store these in collections depends on the operations that you need to perform.

Comment: Thats amazing, Alvaro. Thank you so much for this. I will def study this! One question - Did you do this with immutable data types here? I mean i can read code but a bit lost if this is done with immutable data types:D

Comment: Yes, all immutable. Case classes are immutable by default and List is immutable.

Comment: Thank you so much! I get it now! :D This made my life so much easier..

Comment: @matkenis Please accept this answer if it did answer your question, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply have an ID ( 0 to 51 for 52 cards ) and use this :

((ID % 13) + 1) = card value ( 1, 2, 3, ... 13 )

( ID / 13 ) = Suit ( 0,1,2,3 = Hearts, .... )

If you use Jokers, then (ID/13) would equal 4 for the 2 Jokers.

So you keep an array of 52/54 numbers which would be your deck.  You keep all these Card ID in this array in any order you want.